# How do I add a custom script on a specific page?

Tags: 7, javascript

I wanted to add custom JavaScript code on certain nodes.
I have written this code in the *html.tpl.php* template, but this doesn't work. (*donate* is the path alias for a node.)

```php
<?php if(arg(0) == 'DONATE'): ?>
  <script>
    (function() {
      // ...
    );
  </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: then what's the problem just put your js inside script tag.

Comment: did you read question? :) I want that script only on specific page.

Comment: in your situation arg(0) will be 'node' and arg(1) will be ID of a node

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<?php
$node = menu_get_object();
if ($node && $node->nid == DONATE_NODE_ID):
?>
<script></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But a better way would be to:

1. Wrap your script in Drupal.behaviors:

   ```
   (function ($) {
     Drupal.behaviors.NameOfYourTheme = {
       attach: function (context, settings) {
         // Your JS code goes here.
       }
     }
   })(jQuery);
   ```
2. Call `drupal_add_js()` in `hook_preprocess_page()`. This code would go to `template.php`:

   ```
   function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
     $node = menu_get_object();
     if ($node && $node->nid == DONATE_NODE_ID) {
       drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME') . '/path/to/js.js');
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Okay the first did work, since I wanted it on header. not sure if we can do same with drupal_add_js function. Thanks much.

Comment: Yep, `drupal_add_js()` will append the script to the list of scripts in header.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in your theme's template file

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

 $node = menu_get_object();
 if ($node && $node->nid == "node id of this node here"):
    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/events.js');
  }

  $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution because you can use path aliases w/ wildcards. https://gist.github.com/bjmiller121/3d6cf18ceccc8de5c057

Note: this solution uses aliases so it probably only makes sense to use it when URLs are very predictable and do not change.

In your theme's template.php (or custom module)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html
 * @param $variables
 */
function themename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $alias = drupal_get_path_alias(current_path());
  $urls = array(
    'example/url',
    'example/url/*',
  );
  $patterns = implode("\n", $urls);

  if (drupal_match_path($alias, $patterns)) {
    // Do something only on ther specified URL patterns
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html.tpl.php file, use below code to implement javascript on your node.

```
if(arg(0) == 'node') {
        $arr_list_of_nodes = array('3', '4', '7');
        $nid = arg(1);

        if(in_array($nid, $arr_list_of_nodes)) {
                ?><script type=""text/javascript"" language=""Javascript"">
                        //your js code
                </script><?php
        }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Thanks!